# Filter Array By Another Array (AngularJS)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I have a array of objects. the object contains: 

code

name.

example:

```
var fullList = [
      {"code":10,"name":"example 10"},
      {"code":50,"name":"example 50"},
      {"code":60,"name":"example 60"}
   ]
```

I have another array with only code, like:

```
var filterBy = [10, 50]
```

I want to create 2 new array:

First - contains only objects that their code in "filterBy"
Second - contains only objects that their code not (!) in "filterBy"

how can i do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in a function as the filter expression

```
<div ng-repeat="a in fullList | filter: myFilterBy">
  {{ a }}
</div>
```

and then

```
$scope.myFilterBy = function(e) {
  return filterBy.indexOf(e.code) !== -1;
}
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7tda0bbL/

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 arrays as follows -

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
angular.forEach(fullList, function(obj, key) {
    var indx = filterArray(obj);
    if (indx > -1) {
      arr1.push(obj);
    } else {
      arr2.push(obj);
    }
});
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);

function filterArray(arrObj) {
    return [10, 50].indexOf(arrObj.code);
};
```